# Suggestions for activating front facing camera within Safari on iPad

Tags: ios, html, ipad, camera

I'm trying to create a *kiosk-style customer registration process* with an iPad, but doing it an an entirely web-based environment, rather than a purpose-built app.

During the registration process, the user is required to take a photo of their own face using the iPad camera.

I have been experimenting with the HTML5 Media Capture tools, but unfortunately, this always defaults to the iPad's back camera, rather than the front-facing camera. This means the user must then switch to the front facing camera, which isn't ideal as part of the user experience.

I can't see any way of forcing the iPad to default to the front camera in the device settings, and my searches haven't revealed any way of doing this with *HTML* only.

I've had a look at apps such as "Picup", but they don't seem to offer much more than is already achievable with *HTML5* with regard to camera control.

Can anyone offer any suggestions? Does anyone know of any other iOS apps (like Picup) that might give the ability to activate the camera for uploading images in a form, but can be configured to use the front facing camera as default?

Or am I going to have to go down the path of creating a purpose-built app to get the control I need?

Any suggestions would be welcomed, and thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The Media API currently doesn't allow you to distinguish between front and rear cameras, so there is currently no method (that I know of) that allows you to select the front camera.

However I would suggest perhaps building your app the way you are, but using PhoneGap Build (which can package your app into an iOS app) and the Camera Plugin (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html) which does allow you to specify the front camera (see [options](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions_options)->cameraDirection) apparently (I haven't tried it myself).